# How do I use the onmouseover function to highlight a portion of an SVG image?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a SVG image of the map of Europe, with partitions for each country represented by paths. If I hover over a country, I want the opacity of the country that is hovered over to change to 0.5. I've tried defining a JavaScript function to call, but nothing seems to happen when I hover over a country. Here is my SVG code for reference, and the JavaScript I've tried to write:

```
<script
    xlink:href="../map.js"
    id="script99"
    type="text/javascript" />
 <g
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer2"
    class="section"
    inkscape:label="paths"
    transform="translate(0,-230.143)">
   <path
      style="fill:#3399ff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.06832593px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
      d="m 170.10418,253.29039 0.16365,-1.29169 2.4003,-0.68196 2.91852,-0.51346 0.90921,0.17651 0.12727,0.61776 -0.50914,0.82636 -0.14547,1.3639 -1.51836,1.04298 -0.82736,0.85845 c 0,0 -0.28187,0.48137 -0.33642,0.48939 -0.0545,0.007 -0.99103,-0.7381 -0.99103,-0.7381 l -0.66371,-0.43325 -0.60915,-1.37191 z"
      id="ukraine" 
      onclick="Here(id)"
      onmouseover="MouseOver(this)"
      inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
      />
```

```
function MouseOver(elem){
    elem.opacity = 0.1;
}
```

Comment: did you try css hover ?

Comment: @MrJ, how would I go about doing this? I don't have an external css file that i'm using to style the svg

Comment: @MrJ No, I only wrap this code in svg tags. I figured since I could implement onclick this way, I would be able to implement onmouseover this way as well

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the inline styles and I've putted them in a `<style>` tag. As you may see the `<style>` tag is inside the svg element.

To yous styles I've added

```
#ukraine:hover {
      fill-opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

This is the demo:

```html
<svg viewBox="170 250 7 7">
  <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        #ukraine {
  fill: #3399ff;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 0.06832593px;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

#ukraine:hover {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
        ]]> 
  </style>
  
   <path id="ukraine"
      d="m 170.10418,253.29039 0.16365,-1.29169 2.4003,-0.68196 2.91852,-0.51346 0.90921,0.17651 0.12727,0.61776 -0.50914,0.82636 -0.14547,1.3639 -1.51836,1.04298 -0.82736,0.85845 c 0,0 -0.28187,0.48137 -0.33642,0.48939 -0.0545,0.007 -0.99103,-0.7381 -0.99103,-0.7381 l -0.66371,-0.43325 -0.60915,-1.37191 z"
       
      /> 
</svg>
```